# How to include functions in script files into PowerShell module

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I'm using PowerShell 5.0 and trying to write a multi-files module.
The module's folder structure looks like this:

```
/FooModule
--- FooModule.psd1
--- FooModule.psm1
--- AnotherScriptFile.ps1
```

The manifest file FooModule.psd1 is customized like follows:

```
@{
    ModuleVersion = '0.0.1'
    GUID = ...
    Author = ...
    CompanyName = ..
    Copyright = ...
    Description = ...
    PowerShellVersion = '5.0'
    ClrVersion = '4.0'
    RootModule = "FooModule.psm1"
    FunctionsToExport = '*'
    CmdletsToExport = '*'
    VariablesToExport = '*'
    AliasesToExport = '*'
    # HelpInfoURI = ''
    # DefaultCommandPrefix = ''
}
```

I put these at the beginning of FooModule.psm1:

```
Push-Location $PSScriptRoot
.\AnotherScriptFile.ps1
Pop-Location
```

AnotherScriptFile.ps1 looks like this:

```
Write-Host "Imported!"
function Get-FooFunction($val)
{
    return "Foo Bar";
}
```

I think, when I import the module, it will read AnotherScriptFile.ps1's functions and variables into module's scope, and get exported.
Sadly, after I imported the module with `Import-Module .\FooModule.psm1` in the module's folder, calling `Get-FooFunction` gave me an error says `Get-FooFunction` does not exist, `'Write-Host "Imported!"` was called though.

What's the correct way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the scripts in the `ScriptsToProcess` array within your module manifest:

```
# Script files (.ps1) that are run in the caller's environment prior to importing this module.
ScriptsToProcess = @('.\AnotherScriptFile.ps1')
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply. I tried, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Another way would be to dot source the file (with another dot) in your `FooModule.psm1`. Try this:

`. .\AnotherScriptFile.ps1`

Comment: I tried, but this time, an error occured, says `..\AnotherScriptFile.ps1 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,script file, or operable program.`. Working directory was set to the root of the module though.

Comment: Sorry, due to the new line, I didn't see the space between the `dot operator` `.` and the file path `.\AnotherScriptFile.ps1`. I changed the 2nd line of FooModule.psm1 to -> `.[space].\AnotherScriptFile.ps1`, everything worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Any idea why ScriptsToProcess doesn't work? Is it not able to load function definitions into the environment?

Comment: @Blaisem Sorry, hard to say without seeing your script. I would suggest asking a new question on StackOverflow - I am sure someone will be able to help you. BR

Comment: I got it to work for functions by loading them via ScriptsToProcess in a submodule, then loading the submodule via NestedModule into my parent module. It seems NestedModule is really reliable for importing everything. The ScriptsToProcess has been wonderful for loading classes. The member is loaded before nested modules though, in case anyone can use this info later.